# Unity3d GridlayoutGroup element not visible

Tags: c#, layout, unity-game-engine

Working on a Unity3d-project, we are having an issue that we can't solve: We use a GridLayoutGroup with several children to provide a Drag'n'Drop-System. Therefore we have one GridLayoutGroup fixed in the scene and one panel width a dynamically created amount of children via script.

If we execute the script by command in another script, everything works fine and all the slots are visible and working. But if the script is executed automatically by OnLevelWasLoaded, the slots are created in the right position, but not visible. Even if the background and everything else is disabled, we can not see the slots.

I hope, you have a possible solution for our problem :)

Comment: Checked their size/scale? Do you perform any manipulations in Awake event with GridLayoutGroup or any script on the same gameObject?

Comment: @Utamaru: We adjust scale and position immediately after instantiating the slot-prefabs (tested and working, if the script is executed manually). Other manipulations are not performed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that `OnLevelWasLoaded()` fires before `Awake()` and you're trying to instantiate your prefabs when none of the UI components are initialized (most of the time this happens in `Awake()`). I recommend to move your code from `OnLevelWasLoaded()` to `OnEnable()` (for example) or to any other MonoBehaviour event that would satisfy your needs.

Comment: Also please don't forget to report about results. I'm really curious if this was causing your problems.

Comment: That indeed seems to be the reason (and solution) for the problem. Thanks a lot!